# get the value and use that value as check to process next steps in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to check the  distinct "Status" columnin 1 table and and if that Status='Complete' then I have to call different other Stored Procedures. How can I retrieve the value from the sample code below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEMP_KK()
RETURNS STRING NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$

var load_status=`SELECT DISTINCT TABLESTATUS from "PLNG_ANALYSIS"."LOAD"."LET_LOAD_VERIFICATION";`
var load_check = snowflake.execute({sqlText: load_status});

if (load_check='Complete') /* HOW DO i get the TABLESTATUS value returned from above select statement */
{
CALL ABC();
  
CALL XYZ();
}
$$;
CALL TEMP_KK();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that query returns single row:

```
var load_status=`SELECT DISTINCT TABLESTATUS from "PLNG_ANALYSIS"."LOAD"."LET_LOAD_VERIFICATION";`
var load_check = snowflake.execute({sqlText: load_status});

load_check.next();

if(load_check.getColumnValue(1) == 'Complete') {
...
}
```